# Battery voltage isolated monitoring on Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, batteries, voltage-measurement

Is it safe to directly measure high capacity battery (100 Ah to 300 Ah) voltage with Microcontroller's Analog to Digital Converter (ADC)? 
Would it be enough to use just a simple voltage divider to do this?

Battery voltage types to be measured are 2V and 12V.

Answer (score 2):

That size of battery *could* provide several tens of amps to whatever load it connects to. This means that hanging a simple ADC and voltage divider off it may incur significant errors if the ground return current is high. It could even damage the ADC if not done with due care and attention.

I'd be tempted to "isolate" the ADC with a differential amplifier. The differential amplifier produces an output that can be ground referenced to the ADC circuit rather than ground referenced to the negative leg of the battery: -

[image]

Battery would connect across V1 and V2. Use high value resistors to prevent significant discharge current over a long time period depleting the battery. R1 and R2 can be in the several Mohm range.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. However, since I will be only monitor a single battery cell, I think the voltage to be measured would not be high enough to cause any unfortunate discharging event. What if I just use large R values for the voltage divider to limit discharging current?

Comment: @HacLe your comment makes no sense. Have I mentioned an unfortunate high-voltage discharging event? Have I assumed anything about the battery voltage? I only talk about current with the inference being that the size of the return current is likely to be high and therefore drop a significant voltage across ground return wires thus leading to measurement errors or worse.